# Get plain password on register

Tags: password, user-registration

Does anybody knows how could I get the plain password (via hook) in the moment a user registers and before it is hashed?

Thanks

Comment: May I ask: Why?

Comment: I need to save it in another external (no wordpress) service. I cannot use wp_check_password there.

Comment: That's not a good idea! Then save the hash and compare it.

Comment: Why it's not? I would hash them my way so I can make my own check...Saving the hash wouldn't be a solution for me as I want the users to log in with the same password, and the hash is one way encoded.

Comment: There is no such hook - that would be a huge security flaw.

Comment: Sounds dangerous what your trying to do, but your explanation sounds somewhat reasonable if you're aware of what you're doing. Upvoting to see where this goes.

Comment: Why can't you use `wp_check_password()`? Is it a non-PHP site/service?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into it, but any hook on the page that processes the new user registration will have access to the `$_POST` data and as such you could get it from there.

I agree with the other comments above, you should be able to use use the WordPress hash and check the password on the other website. Would be more sustainable and less susceptible to alterations in future.